# Extend/override prototype function while keeping scope of external file

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

In an external js (person.js) file I have something such as this:

```
var user = 'John';

function Person() { );

Person.prototype.sayHello = function() { 
  console.log('Hello ' + user);
}

Person.prototype.init = function() { 
  this.sayHello();
}
```

How can I override the sayHello method in my javascript without modifying original file?  If I predefine it after loading but before calling init() it sort of works but I don't have access the user variable defined in the scope of person.js.

In another file:

```
Person.prototype.sayHello = function() { 
  console.log('Good morning ' + user);
}

var p = new Person();
p.init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var user` outside any function creates a variable in the global scope, so you can access it from any other file by simply using its name.

However, if your code is running e.g. in the nodejs environment where files have their own scopes you are out or luck - JavaScript does not have nice introspection tools that let you snoop into foreign scopes.

Comment: it is client side and yes you are right about the scope. In my actual situation it doesn't work - as user is not defined. I have not been able to really track down the issue. I am using Segment.io's open source analytic.js and need to modify the GA.prootype.initialize() function.

Comment: No. Here's the actual function I need to override https://github.com/segmentio/analytics.js/blob/master/analytics.js#L6216

Comment: And which variable do you want to access? Anyway, the whole file is wrapped in a function so it's impossible to access any `var` in there from outside.

Comment: Here's my custom script which attempts to override the initialize function (line 40). But user.id() throws errors doing it that way.
https://gist.github.com/cyberwombat/41edc9c87df40d37bf55

Comment: Since any solution won't fit in an answer here (because the question as you posted it is already answered) it'd probably be a good idea to continue this in the [**SO chat**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51950/discussion-between-yashua-and-thiefmaster)